# Maximum of Sub-Exponential and its Tail Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, exponential-distribution

> Consider zero-mean sub-exponential random variables $\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ (**not necessarily independent**) with parameters $(\nu,  \alpha)$. That is,
> $$\mathbb E[\exp\{\lambda X\}] \le \exp\{\nu^2\lambda^2/2\}, \qquad ^\forall |\lambda| < 1/\alpha.$$
> Check whether $\max_{1\le i \le n}X_i$ is sub-exponential, and if so, its tail probability .

This is what I want to study.

If each $X_i$ is independent, I guess I can easily see $Y := \max_{1\le i \le n}X_i$ is sub-exponential using the following property:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb E[\exp\{\lambda Y\}] & \le \mathbb E[\exp\{\lambda \sum_{i=1}^nX_i\}]\\
& = \mathbb E \left(\exp\{\lambda X\}\right)^n \\
& \le \exp\{n\nu^2\lambda^2/2\}
\end{align}$$

But, I can't use this directly when $X_i$ are not independent. So, I need some help about the properties of  $Y := \max_{1\le i \le n}X_i$ w.r.t. sub-exponentials.

Any comment about this question would be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this an equivalent definition only when $\mathbb{E}X = 0$? At least according to Vershynin's high dimensional probability book where he defines sub-exponential rvs as satisfying the condition $P(|X|\geq t)\leq 2\exp(-t/c)$.

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake, I should have denoted the zero mean r.v $X_i$.

Comment: The condition implies the random variables in question have zero mean, actually.

Comment: Also, your proof is not correct in the case of independence

Answer (score 0):

Union bounding,
$P(e^{tY}\geq u)\leq nP(e^{tX}\geq u)$. Namely, $Y$ is sub-exponential.